# get a report of the last 7 days divided by day with google analytics reporting api

Tags: javascript, google-analytics-api

i need to build retrive data devided by day for build a graph of the last 7 days.

following this guide: 
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/web-js

dateRanges[] only accept two range.

can you help me?

sorry for my bad english... not my native language

Comment: what have You tried?  seems the 2nd sample is pretty solid to show the workout..

Comment: i've tried to add multiple range in dateRanges[] but according to the docs you can only ask for two range

Comment: ok solved! need to specify 'ga:date' into the 'dimensions' array in the request fields.

Comment: This helped me a lot! To get the distribution of values over time as in the UI, putting 'ga:date' in the dimensions is the key.

Answer (score 3):

**1.** You should be adding `ga:date` in your dimension array. It's good to know that by doing this you won't be doing as many request you would be doing by looping thru a `dateRange` yourself, this way the `DateRangeObject` will hold only values for the dates that fall within the respective ranges.

**2.** Supposing that you are trying to get back the page-views of certain `pagePath` day by day.

Your reportRequest should be something like this:

```
'reportRequests': [
            {
                'viewId': VIEW_ID,
                'dateRanges': [{'startDate': '2019-02-13', 'endDate': '2019-02-15'}],
                'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:pageviews'}],
                'samplingLevel': 'SMALL',
                'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:pagePath'}, {'name': 'ga:date'}],
                'dimensionFilterClauses': [{
                    'filters': [{
                        'dimensionName': 'ga:pagePath',
                        'operator': 'EXACT',
                        'expressions': ['SomeExpression']
                    }]
                }]
            }]
```